# Make a hierachel value of a json file a variable

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to access a json file value that is multiple hierarchical layers deep. I found a question that show me how to do it, but I'm trying to do it with one of those layers being a variable.

If the json file looks something like

```
barnes -> value that stays the same -> split second
noble -> value that stays the same -> the ocean
chapters -> value that stays the same -> harry potter
```

and this goes on for, 20 lines

I have a list of publishers that I want to pull the title for, so I've tried, also the publisher only has one value im looking for:

```
for i in listex:
    listex.append(books[i]['valuethatstaysthesame']['title'])
```

It doesn't let me index it. The expected output would be printing all the titles

so if the list was

```
listex = ['barnes', 'noble']
```

the expected output would be:

split second, the ocean

Comment: Can you add a sample of the input, please?

Comment: @TheNavigat done!

Comment: @SoloTriesToLearn Can you add exact sample not "something like"?